# Don't stop background audio (i.e Spotify) when playing a muted video in a canvas

Tags: ios, html, canvas, spotify, banner

My goal is to play a video in a HTML5 canvas ad banner but as soon the muted video auto runs the audio on iOS (i.e Spotify) stops playing.

How can I prevent this?

Any help much appreciated!